# Find records created in a period of 24hours (not especially the last 24hrs)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQLServer 2012 and I have a table timestamped like that :

```
Id           INT      NOT NULL,  --PK
IdUser       INT      NOT NULL   --FK from table USER
-- Some other fields
CreationDate DATETIME NOT NULL
```

This table records some type of action made by the user.
I'm trying to find **IF** a user did this type of action more than 20 times (ie there is 20 records with the same IdUser in that table) in a period of 24 hours.

The problem is I'm not trying to retrieve the records in the last 24 hours, but **the records in a period of 24 hours (from the 1st record to today)**

This is what I wrote :

```
SELECT IdUser 
FROM MyTable
WHERE IdUser = 1 
    AND CreationDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() -- <= WRONG
```

But the `WHERE` clause doesn't fit my needs as I have no idea how to translate "*seek 20 records from the user id=1 in a period of 24 hours, not especially the last 24 hours*" in SQL

**SAMPLE**
Let's say our user Id=1 did 154 times this action. So I have 154 records in my table, with the datetime of the record.

```
IdUser = 1 ; CreationDate = 2016-07-29 12:24:54.590
IdUser = 1 ; CreationDate = 2016-07-29 16:51:55.856
IdUser = 1 ; CreationDate = 2016-07-27 14:12:36.125
(151 omitted rows)
```

What I'm seeking is if I can find 20 records in a period of 24 hours for a particular user. In this sample, only the 2 firsts are on a period of 24 hours. In my case, I'm seeking if there is 20 or more records in this period.

Could some one help me ?
Thank you

Comment: If you know how to use DATEADD(), why don't you just use it to get 24 hours instead of 1 day?

Comment: Just use GROUP BY IdUser HAVING COUNT(CreationDate)>20 to get users with at least 20 actions. Regarding date you can use the same dateadd function by passing the start or end date/time as parameter

Comment: @RamGrandhi I don't know if this will give the desired result, because his "group" could be _any_ 24 hour period.

Comment: @alexb:  could you add some sample data for few users and expected result

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Still I suppose it should work because whatever the 24 hours is, it is filtered in the where clause and group by works on the results. And if query is about looking for only a particular userid, then simple count should suffice

Comment: @RamGrandhi Ok, I change a little bit your suggestion to really fit my needs (I simplify my question compared to my "real" DB), and it looks like it's working as I get the desired result. You should post it as an answer...

Comment: @AlexB Are you looking for a particular userid or any user who performed action for more than 20 times in given period?

Comment: @RamGrandhi I was seeking for any userid who perform this action in a period of 24hrs ; iduser=1 what just a simplification to let people focused on the period

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A rather painful way to do this (performance-wise) is with a `join`/`group by` or `apply` operator.

The `apply` should be better from a performance perspective:

```
select t.*
from t cross apply
     (select count(*) as cnt
      from t t2
      where t2.iduser = t.iduser and
            t2.creationdate >= t.creationdate and
            t2.creationdate < dateadd(day, 1, t.creationdate)
     ) t24
where t24.cnt >= 20;
```

An index on `(iduser, creationdate)` is a win for this query.

Comment: beat me to the punch :)

Comment: I will consider your answer but I admit I never used `cross apply`, so I will learn about these keywords. However, this query will be transformed in LINQ, so not sure that optimisation won't be "overriden" by LINQ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried declaring a DateTime variable and setting the date you want to query??

Also, if you want only 'n' records, you can use the TOP 'n' CLAUSE. Even, you you can use TOP n% to get a percentage. (By the way, TOP is available starting with SQLServer 2008)

```
DECLARE @DATE DATETIME = '20160601' --YYYYMMDD

SELECT TOP 20 IdUser 
FROM MyTable
WHERE IdUser = 1 
    AND CreationDate BETWEEN DATEADD(day, -1, @DATE) AND @DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the value for the @starttime as needed

`DECLARE @starttime DATETIME
SELECT IdUser 
FROM MyTable
WHERE CreationDate BETWEEN @starttime and DATEADD(HOUR, 24, @starttime)
GROUP BY IdUser
HAVING COUNT(CreationDate) > 20`

Answer (score 0):

```
        --This will count all records occurring 24 hours after the first instance of a record
SELECT t1.IdUser, T1.CreationDate, COUNT(0) AS InstancesIn24Hrs 
FROM MyTable t1
JOIN MyTable t2 ON T1.IdUser = T2.IdUser AND t2.CreationDate 
                     BETWEEN t1.CreationDate 
                              AND 
                             DATEADD(day, 1, t1.CreationDate) 
WHERE t1.IdUser = 1 
    GROUP BY t1.IdUser, T1.CreationDate
    ORDER BY T1.CreationDate
```